# Which DLLs are requied for task in Azure Batch?

Tags: azure, dll, batch-processing, azure-batch

My question is related to [Azure Batch example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-dotnet-get-started/). Therefore if you do not examine the example, my question will not make any sense.

In this example, total seven NuGet packages are required for the TaskApplication project. However when uploading to Azure, only one of these DLLs are uploaded, namely *Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll* (Line 103 of Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Samples.DotNetTutorial.Program.cs). If I exclude this DLL too, task returns non-zero exit code when executed on Azure. It would be clear for me if all the DLLs are included. Why just this one is uploaded with TaskAplication.exe?

Answer (score 0):

The TaskApplication project pulls those other DLLs in as references because the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage assembly specifies them as dependencies. However, TaskApplication references members that are self-contained within Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, and the other assemblies are not needed for it to execute.

If you wish, you can remove the other (unnecessary) references from the TaskApplication project without adverse effects.

Comment: As I understand what you said, I should upload DLLs which are used. However since I do not know which ones are used, it is best to upload all of them.  Of course you can try and see the absence of which DLL cause problems. But again it seem error prone. IMHO, in an example all the DLLs should be uploaded. No need for complications.

Comment: By the way, it may be the case that Azure supplies other DLLs itself. They are all dependencies of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll